# Can I retrieve records that have grandchild records that satisfy a criterion?

Tags: soql

I have three tables `Loan__c`, `Tag__c` and a join table, `TagAssignment__c`. I'm trying to find loans that satisfy a criteria that includes only loans that have tag assignments with specific names. Pseudo SOQL would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    AppraisalDate__c,
    RateExpiration__c,
    (SELECT Id, Tag__r.Name FROM TagAssignments__r)
FROM Loan__c
WHERE (
    AppraisalDate__c < :fourDaysAgo
    AND TagAssignments__r.Tag__r.Name INCLUDES 'Aprsl Expiring Soon'
)
OR (
    RateExpiration__c < :fourDaysAgo
    AND TagAssignments__r.Tag__r.Name INCLUDES 'Rate Expiring Soon'
)
```

Is this possible with SOQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LIKE` operator instead of INCLUDES.INCLUES will work for multi select datatype.

Try with below query.

```
SELECT
Id,
AppraisalDate__c,
RateExpiration__c,
(SELECT Id, Tag__r.Name FROM TagAssignments__r)
FROM Loan__c 
WHERE Id IN(select Loan__c from TagAssignments__c WHERE (Tag__r.Name LIKE 'Aprsl Expiring Soon%') OR (Tag__r.Name LIKE 'Rate Expiring Soon%'))
      AND (AppraisalDate__c < LAST_N_DAYS:4 OR RateExpiration__c < LAST_N_DAYS:4)
```

Refer the [Date Formats and Date Literals in WHERE Clauses](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)